# How to mask Jenkins Environment variable value as password in bash while connecting to server using Pipelines

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins-pipeline

I am pulling  the db password from the server using Jenkins job and storing in environment variable in one of the stage in Jenkins pipeline and in another stage I can able to connect the app server with the stored environment variable as password successfully but the password is displayed as plain text on Jenkins console,I want to mask the password on Jenkins console(I don't want to manually update password as CredentialsId, passwords are dynamically pull from remote server) .Can someone please let me know how i can achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: Your option is basically the `credentials` plugin though. You can potentially dynamically retrieve it though. We would need to see more context.

Comment: Hi Matt, not sure how can we achieve it by credentials plugin dynamically using jenkins pipelines, can you please provide more details.

Comment: stage('Build') {
            steps {
     
      bat "H hostname:port -U username -P ${abc} }}                                      storing the password in below jenkins env.abc                                                              env.abc = sh('some bash script to pull password from remote',returnStdout: true).trim()

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `Jenkins Piplines` to execute shell script to achieve it